# Does rsync create duplicate files on destination

Tags: rsync

In case the rsync is aborted and restarted again ,will rynsc copy same file twice to the destination and create duplicate copies on the destination?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and it just rewrites the files. I didn't end up with any duplicate files.

The command I used: **rsync -a folderone/ foldertwo**

**-a** copies all attributes of the original files.

(Tested on OSMC Linux on RPi3)